# Backup fails, not enough space

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup

I have Back Up set up to back up to my Ubuntu One account, but for some reason when it is backing up it tries and then gives me the error: 
`Backup location is too small.  Try using one with more space.`

I don't think my Ubuntu One account has too little space, as it has backed up before, at least I believe it has as when I check my account it shows files from the backup there.

This isn't a major problem, just a minor annoyance.

Comment: What program do you use to do the backup? Which directories do you want to backup?

Comment: The default backup program. Sorry for the freaskishly late answer

Comment: No worries :-), please add that info and also *which directories* you want to backup and *to where* you want to back them up to your question. You could also show us error messages or a screenshot in your question.

Comment: Well, I said that it auto-backs-up to my free Ubuntu 1 account, and when I get the chance I'll add the rest.

Comment: How much Ubuntu One space do you have? Just the free account? Are you backing up your entire system or just your home folder?